# Formik component=“textarea” multiline in placeholder

Tags: reactjs, formik

How print the newline/return in placeholder text in Formik textarea.
I've tried \n, nothing seems to be working.

```
// &#13;, &#10; didn't work
<Field
      className="form-control"
      component="textarea"
      name="dayWiseItinerary"
      rows="6"
      placeholder="
      day 1: Temple visit,&#13;&#10;
      day 2: Jungle barbeque,\n
      day 3: Waterfall visit in the evening,\n
      day 4: Visit UNESCO World Heritage Site,\n
      day 5: Art gallery show,\n
      day 6: Visit grand swimming pool,\n
      day 7: Visit to Blue fort
      "
    />
```

[image: textarea]

Comment: You can try [Template_literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: @keikai is correct, template literal will allow a placeholder prop text to span multiple lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Multi-line_strings) allow you to specify a multi-line string of text.

```
<textarea
  cols={40}
  placeholder={`day 1: Temple visit,&#13;&#10;
day 2: Jungle barbeque,\n
day 3: Waterfall visit in the evening,\n
day 4: Visit UNESCO World Heritage Site,\n
day 5: Art gallery show,\n
day 6: Visit grand swimming pool,\n
day 7: Visit to Blue fort`}
  rows={20}
/>
```

[image]

**Note**: Since this is a string template literal, be mindful of the whitespace within the templating. Notice above that the leading whitespace for each line is absent. Also notice now the newlines `\n` are rendered.

[image: Edit kind-dan-x9qwf]

Answer (score 6):

```
<Field component="textarea" rows="4" value={""}></Field>
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @Drew Reese answer, and regarding his note about whitespaces, you can also do this:

```
<textarea
  cols={40}
  placeholder={'day 1: Temple visit,&#13;&#10;'
    + 'day 2: Jungle barbeque,\n'
    + 'day 3: Waterfall visit in the evening,\n'
    + 'day 4: Visit UNESCO World Heritage Site,\n'
    + 'day 5: Art gallery show,\n'
    + 'day 6: Visit grand swimming pool,\n'
    + 'day 7: Visit to Blue fort'}
  rows={20}
/>
```