# How to set Formik muiltiple select initialvalues to an array/list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I am using a form created with Formik, with a multiple-select input field to capture data about an event, which is attended by many people (the multiple-select input field allows selection of the many people).  When submitting this form to create a database record, it outputs an array, which I then deconstruct into separate rows (e.g. event A, member A; then event A, member B, etc).  These rows are then stored in a MySQL database.

I want to use the same Formik form for editing purposes.  When loading the previously saved data back into the form, prior to a user being able to edit the data, I pass the previously saved values to the multiple-select field by setting the Formik prop `initialvalues`.  This works fine with a multiple-select input field as long as only one value has been selected - the data passed in `initialvalues` is highlighted in the multiple-select field on screen.  But in the majority of cases, many rows in the multiple-select will need to be highlighted, not just one.

I therefore tried passing `initialvalues` an array of data.  This compiles OK, but then, on-screen, no rows in the multiple-select field are highlighted.  No errors are shown, but it isn't working.

I couldn't find anything in the Formik docs about this, and no previously answered questions on Stack Overflow (a similar question has been asked, but not answered).  Can anyone advise how I can achieve this?

Below is my code:

**Example A:** This results in the row 'forename 1' being highlighted in the multiple-select field

```
      const initialValues = {
        MemberMemberId: 'forename1',
      };
```

**Example B:** This compiles OK, but results in no rows multiple-select field being highlighted

```
      const initialValues = {
        MemberMemberId: ['forename1', 'forename2'],
      };
```

Following is the full code for the edit page:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Formik, Form, Field, ErrorMessage } from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup'; //yup does form validation
import axios from 'axios';
import { useMutation } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import { useRecoilState } from 'recoil'
import { memberEventButtonClickedState } from '../Atoms/atoms'
import Button from '@mui/material/Button'
import Snackbar from '@mui/material/Snackbar';
import Alert from '@mui/material/Alert';
import { PatternFormat } from 'react-number-format';

//react-query useMutation code
const useMemberEventsCreateMutation = () => {
  return useMutation((formPayload) => {
    return axios.put('http://localhost:3001/memberevents/ById', formPayload);
  });
}; 

//Variable to store Tailwind css for 'Field' elements of Formik function
const formikField =
  'my-px block px-2.5 pb-2.5 pt-4 w-full text-sm text-gray-900 bg-transparent rounded-lg border border-gray-400 appearance-none focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 focus:border-blue-600 peer';

//Variable to store Tailwind css for 'Label' elements of Formik function
const formikLabel =
  'absolute text-base text-gray-500 duration-300 transform -translate-y-4 scale-75 top-2 z-10 origin-[0] bg-white dark:bg-gray-900 px-2 peer-focus:px-2 peer-focus:text-blue-600 peer-placeholder-shown:scale-100 peer-placeholder-shown:-translate-y-1/2 peer-placeholder-shown:top-6 peer-focus:top-1 peer-focus:scale-75 peer-focus:-translate-y-4 left-1';

//Variable to store Tailwind css for 'Select' elements of Formik function
const formikSelect =
  'my-px block px-2.5 pb-2.5 pt-4 w-full text-sm text-gray-900 bg-transparent rounded-lg border border-gray-400 focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 focus:border-blue-600 peer';

//Function for date fields formatting, using react-number-format
function DateField({ field }) {
  return (
    <PatternFormat
      {...field}
      format="####/##/##"
      mask={['Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'M', 'M', 'D', 'D']}
      className={formikField}
      placeholder="YYYY/MM/DD"
    />
  );
}


//Main function/custom useMutation Hook - creates Formik form
function MemberEventsEdit(props) {
  const { mutate } = useMemberEventsCreateMutation();


  // //Formik initial values
  const initialValues = {
    MemberMemberId: [{'forename1','forename2'}],
    EventEventId: props?.memberEventData?.EventEventId ?? '', //the two questions marks mean ignore if null
    event_date: props?.memberEventData?.event_date ?? ''
  };

  // Yup field validation
  const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    member_id: Yup.number()
      .required('*Member ID is required'),
    event_id: Yup.number()
      .required('*Event ID is required'),
    event_date: Yup.string()
      .required('*Event Date is required'),
  });

  // Recoil global state to trigger data table refresh after event edit button is clicked
  const [buttonisClicked, setButtonIsClicked] = useRecoilState(memberEventButtonClickedState)

  // State for event data to populate Event Name dropdown
  const [event, setEvent] = useState([]);
  // console.log(event)
 
   // Gets array of event ids/names from event table
   useEffect(() => {
     axios
       .get('http://localhost:3001/eventdropdown')
       .then((res) => res.data)
       .then((data) => setEvent(data));
   }, []);
 
 
   // State for member data to populate member Name dropdown
   const [member, setMember] = useState([]);
    //  console.log(member)
 
   // Gets array of member ids/names from member table
   useEffect(() => {
     axios
       .get(`http://localhost:3001/memberdropdown`)
       .then((res) => res.data)
       .then((data) => setMember(data));
   }, []);

  // State for MUI snackbar popup open status
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  //State for MUI snackbar popup message
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');

  //State for MUI snackbar popup severity
  const [severity, setSeverity] = useState();

  // Variable for property to close MUI snackbar popup
  const handleClose = (event, reason) => {
    if (reason === 'clickaway') {
      return;
    }
    setOpen(false);
  };

  
  return (
    <>
    <div className="createMemberEventPage px-5 relative">
      <Formik
        enableReinitialize={true}
        initialValues={initialValues}
        validationSchema={validationSchema}
        onSubmit={(values, formik) => {
          mutate(values, {
            onSuccess: () => {
              setOpen(true);
              setMessage('Member event changes saved!');
              setSeverity('success');
              setButtonIsClicked(buttonisClicked + 1); //updates Recoil global state, to trigger data-table refetch of data
              formik.resetForm();

            },
            onError: (response) => {
              setOpen(true);
              setMessage('Error, member event changes not saved!');
              setSeverity('error');
              console.log(response);
            },
          });
        } }
      >
        <Form className="formContainer">
          <h1 className="pb-3 text-xl font-semibold">General Information</h1>

          <div className="pb-2 relative">
            <Field
              className={formikField}
              autoComplete="off"
              id="inputCreateMemberEvent"
              name="event_date"
              placeholder=" "
              component={DateField} />
            <label className={formikLabel}>Event Date</label>
            <ErrorMessage
              name="event_date"
              component="span"
              className="text-red-600" />
          </div>

           <div className="pb-2 relative">
            <Field
              className={formikSelect}
              as="select"
              name="EventEventId"
              id="inputCreateEvent"
            >
              <option>Select an Event Name...</option>
              {event.map((event) => {
                return (
                  <option key={event.event_id} value={event.event_id}>
                    {event.event_name}
                  </option>
                );
              })}
            </Field>
            <label className={formikLabel}>Event Name</label>
            <ErrorMessage
              name="EventEventId"
              component="span"
              className="text-red-600"
            />
          </div> 

          <div className="pb-2 relative">
            <Field
              className={formikSelect}
              as="select"
              name="MemberMemberId"
              id="inputCreateEvent"
              multiple={true}
            >
              <option>Select Member Names...</option>
              {member.map((member) => {
                return (
                  <option key={member.member_id} value={member.member_id}>
                    {member.forename + " " + member.surname}
                  </option>
                );
              })}
            </Field>
            <label className={formikLabel}>Member Name</label>
            <ErrorMessage
              name="MemberMemberId"
              component="span"
              className="text-red-600"
            />
          </div> 

          <div className="flex flex-col items-center pt-4">
            <Button variant="contained" size="large"
/*               className="text-base text-white bg-blue-500 border hover:bg-blue-600 hover:text-gray-100  p-2 px-20 rounded-lg mt-5" */
              type="submit"
            >
              Save Changes
            </Button>
          </div>
          <br></br>
          <br></br>          
          <br></br>
          <br></br>

          <Snackbar 
                open={open} 
                autoHideDuration={5000} 
                onClose={handleClose} 
                anchorOrigin={{
                  vertical: 'bottom',
                  horizontal: 'center',
              }}
              sx={{ position:'absolute'}}
              >
            <Alert
              severity={severity}
              variant="filled"
              sx={{ width: '100%' }}
            >
              {message}
            </Alert>
          </Snackbar>

        </Form>
      </Formik>
    </div></>
  );
}

export default MemberEventsEdit;
```

Comment: You need to add a working example or at least the relevant jsx. It's impossible to tell what's wrong with the info you've provided.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I wasn't sure it would help as it's such a Formik-specific question, but I've added the code for the entire page as requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out based on this post about Formik textareas: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60700899/formik-component-textarea-multiline-in-placeholder)

The solution is to separate each entry that should be highlighted in the multiple-select field with the html line break code - \n.

So in my case the following works:

```
      const initialValues = {
        MemberMemberId: 'forename1 \nforename2',
      };
```